# regular expressions in c++ with a GNU project C and C++ compiler

Tags: c++, regex

i'm trying to write regular expressions in c++ but i keep getting compilation errors. i looked over the web but couldn't find an answer to that.

i'm copy pasted an example such as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/regex>  //<regex> didn't compile
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    string str = "127.0.0.1";
    std::tr1::regex rx("127.0.0.1");
    regex_match(str.begin(), str.end(), rx);
    return 0;
}
```

i'm getting `/tmp/cc0zldN2.o: In function std::tr1::basic_regex<char, std::tr1::regex_traits<char> >::basic_regex(char const*, unsigned int)':.... undefined reference to std::tr1::basic_regex<char, std::tr1::regex_traits<char> >::_M_compile()...`

from what i see this syntax is used in windows. i'm using linux with a GNU project C and C++ compiler.
anyone have references to regex examples that match my compiler?

thanks!

Comment: The `.......` is the *important part*. Do not ever not show the full error message.

Comment: Regarding the example. Do you have to compare strings or actually parse an IP? The way you tried to implement it, it will match on a lot more than pure IPs due to a `.` matching any character - not just a `.`. If you'd like to match a `.` only, escape it (`\.`).

Comment: works ok with gcc 4.7 (using std::regex :)

Comment: it was just an example to try to compile some pattern.. i know it won't work for matching ips..

Comment: It's in 4.7? Nice, think I tried 4.6 only. Having a look later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I checked (about half a year ago), GCC didn't have the actual TR1 implementation. For whatever reason they added the headers, but skipped the implementation (instead of adding some sort of warnings or errors (or simply not deploying the headers)).

If you don't have to use GCC, use MSVC, they've got a complete implementation, or use an alternative library providing regular expressions (PCRE, the GNU one (don't remember it's name), SLRE, etc.).

Comment: i must use g++.. it's part of a course i'm taking.. any other suggestions or i'm gonna skip the use of regexes..?

Comment: Skip regular expressions or use one of the libraries listed above (unless you're not allowed to do that). They're rather easy to use. May I ask you what kind of course this is? If it's some kind of beginner C++ you're most likely meant to implement it using direct string access/modification.

Comment: Sure, it will work. However each computer compiling your code will require the boost files, too. Depending on what you're meant to do, this might be "overkill" though. You could just use `strtol()` to parse the IP byte by byte without having to worry about any regular expressions or dependencies.

Comment: thanks for your help. on e last thing, do u have a recommended tutorial/reference to the boost library?

Comment: The official documentation should include enough examples to get started (actually, the implementation is almost identical to TR1; just using different namespaces).